# What code in SFMC templates triggered the default header and footer and is it required?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, html, content-builder

1. In HTML emails (non-template based), it looks like customer HTML is NOT triggering the default header & footer, how come HTML email are able to go out without default header / footer and still comply with  CAN-SPAM Act?
2. When an email template is created and then Template based email, it seems to showing up default header / footer, why  template trigger default header /footer but html email is not?
   Can we configure default header/footer in Admin settings as NONE? then we can include custom footer directly in the HTML of the temnplate?
3. When I create a template using just the HTML code, I am not triggering the default header / footer? How come? What in drag and drag template creation process is triggering default header / footer that this template is not?

Comment: Just another point, if you use custom template [which does not have default header/footer] you may encounter error and here are methods to overcome... hope this helps https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311736/how-to-debug-ampscript-in-marketing-cloud-email-content-missing-profile-cen?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review this page. [Implement Header and Footer Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_implement_headers_footers.htm&type=5)

> NOTE Insert the code into your custom templates and HTML Paste emails to automatically pull the header and footer for your account setting into your email when you send.
>
> Header code: `<custom type="header" name="header" />`
>
> Footer code: `<custom type="footer" name="footer" />`

Comment: Thanks EazyE for sharing, in this case my question is, is it necessary to call custom header/ footer from account settings? What if we prefer to use custom html that lives in the template HTML instead?

Comment: All I am trying to confirm if that custom type header and footer are NOT a requirement to be inherited from account settings, right? Header and footer can be hardcoded within the template as well as an option, right?

Comment: then add what ever ampscript you want to call the content blocks that you want to use for header and footer

Comment: Got it, so calling header/ footer from account settings is not required, thanks for confirming.